# ASP.net menu only show certain nodes in Web.sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, sitemap

I have a few items apart of my Web.sitemap file that rely on querystring or session variables.
I do not want these items to appear in my menu.

Is there a way to hide it from the menu, but still be in the sitemap (for sitepath control).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this article when I wanted to stop an node from appearing I found this article great:

http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/i-bet-you-didn-know-that-adding-custom.html

ASP.NET does have functionality to control which nodes you want displayed but I believe this is tied to Membership/Roles.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access  the link you provided. The browser says "Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)". Do you know an alternative link?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it...

I just made the title of the siteMapNode I want to be hidden to "[hidden]". In the .cs file the sitemap control sits I did this...

```
protected void rmMenu_ItemDataBound(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Text == "[hidden]")
    e.Item.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use the attribute **show="false"**, like so:

```
<siteMapNode show="false" url="~/admin/submissionsaddedit.aspx" title="Add/Edit Submission"  description="" roles="Administrator, Shortlister, Moderator"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was grabbing that from a project at work that I'm not deeply familiar with. It seems that there's some code down in the actual control to display the navigation that checks the "show" attribute: i.e., skip it if "node["show"] != null && node["show"].ToString() == "false""